# Gauge mediated SUSY breaking

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conservation-laws, gauge-theory, supersymmetry, symmetry-breaking

I have seen it claimed that in SUSY gauge mediated breaking there can be no flavour changing terms because the mediation is flavour blind.

What does this mean and how does it work?